# Complicated Iteration through nested map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a table with values like this:

[image: my data]

I have to accumulate each person (column 'name') above dates and car, computer and meal-prices.
It should look like this:

[image: Summary]

My data structure looks like this:

```
Map<String, Map<Date, List<product_price_object>>> myTable = new TreeMap<>();
```

I am trying to iterate over Map and nested Map and over List. 
Problem is, that I cannot calculate sum of List like:

```
product_list.get(i) + product_list_get(i+1)
```

because I would calculate car_price with computer_price of first row.

```
for(Entry<String, Map<Date, List<LogonuserAllowance>>> entry : history.entrySet()) {

    String currentUser =  entry.getKey();
    user_sum_map.put(currentUser, new TreeMap<>());

    Map<Date, List<LogonuserAllowance>> month_map = entry.getValue();

    for(Entry<Date, List<LogonuserAllowance>> allowance : month_map.entrySet()){
        calender.setTime(allowance.getKey());
        currentMonth = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        user_sum_map.get(currentUser).put(currentMonth, new ArrayList<>());
        BigDecimal newValue = null;
        BigDecimal previousValue = null;
        BigDecimal sum = null;
        //iterate through list
        for (int i = 0; i < allowance.getValue().size(); i++) {                 
            newValue = allowance.getValue().get(i).getPrice();
            previousValue =  user_sum_map.get(currentUser).get(currentMonth).get(i-1);
            sum = previousValue.add(newValue);
            user_sum_map.get(currentUser).get(currentMonth).add(sum);
        }
    }

}
```

I am afraid, that my solution will be to complicated, and maybe there are some 
easier possibilities to iterate and accumulate above month and prices.

Comment: In your example, why are there two entries for Peter in the result table and not one? Also, if the data is in a database, a query to get the result directly would probably be more efficient than retrieving all the data and manipulating it in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by accumulating each person, Please be more specific?The second image confuses as what you want to achieve.

Comment: Second picture shows, that i have grouped everyting at first by the month.
For example at 20.4 and 21.4 i bought two computers. ComputerA at 20.4 costs 2.4 and ComputerB at 21.4 costs 12.4.
Now i want to know, how many money i've spent for computers on month may.